# Beginner CUDA: two dimensional blocks and two dimensional threads?

Tags: cudalink, gpu

This is a follow up question to: [CUDA: setting grid dimensions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1214/cuda-setting-grid-dimensions). The purpose of the question is to understand how Mathematica is interfacing with CUDA's architecture.  I have a related question/request here: [Looking for a working mathematica CUDA port of NVIDIA's nbody.cu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70258/looking-for-a-working-mathematica-cuda-port-of-nvidias-nbody-cu). There is now a follow on question here: [A simple experiment to understand CUDAFunctionLoad](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71304/a-simple-experiment-to-understand-cudafunctionload)

My question is, *"What do the dimensions of the last argument to CUDAFunctionLoad mean, and what does the optional last argument to a CUDAFunction mean, and how does one use the total dimensionality of 5 that is permissible in CUDA?"*

The CUDA runtime model allows two block dimensions and two thread dimensions.  An example, pulled from the "*CUDA by Example* by J. Sanders and E. Kandrot" has this C example:

```
void generate_frame( DataBlock *d, int ticks ) {
dim3 blocks(DIM/16,DIM/16);
dim3 threads(16,16);
kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>( d->dev_bitmap, ticks );
```

dim3 is a built-in CUDA type. It has three dimensions, two of which are usable. Presumably, the third dimension is sitting around waiting for new GPU architectures.

If I understand the documentation for CUDAFunctionLoad correctly, then the mathematica code (taken from the documentation) for blocks and threads goes like this:

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
srcf = FileNameJoin[{$CUDALinkPath, "SupportFiles", "vecAdd.cu"}]

vectorAdd = (*16 blocks*)
 CUDAFunctionLoad[{srcf}, 
  "vecAdd", {{_Integer, _, "Input"}, {_Integer, _, 
    "Input"}, {_Integer, _, "Output"}, _Integer}, 16]

vectorAdd[Range[64], ConstantArray[2, 64], ConstantArray[0, 64], 64] (*works*)

vectorAdd[Range[64], ConstantArray[2, 64], ConstantArray[0, 64], 64, 256] (*also works, 256 threads for each of the 16 blocks ??*)
```

trying a different {blocks,threads} argument for CUDAFunctionLoad:

```
vectorAddALT = (*16 blocks with 32 threads per block??*)
 CUDAFunctionLoad[{srcf}, 
  "vecAdd", {{_Integer, _, "Input"}, {_Integer, _, 
    "Input"}, {_Integer, _, "Output"}, _Integer}, {16, 32}]
```

This works:

```
vectorAddALT[Range[64], ConstantArray[2, 64],  ConstantArray[0, 64], 64]
```

And so does this:

```
vectorAddALT[Range[64], ConstantArray[2, 64], 
 ConstantArray[0, 64], 64, 256] (*an additional 256 threads for each of the 16 blocks??*)
```

But, this doesn't (the original form of the vectorAdd compiled for 16 blocks)

```
vectorAdd[Range[64], ConstantArray[2, 64], ConstantArray[0, 64], {64,64}]
 (*beginner's attempt to have a one dimensional set of blocks each with two dimensional thread indices*)
```

Comment: Craig, I'm sorry that no-one seems to answer your questions about CUDA. I would have to install `CUDALink` first which never worked out of the box on Ubuntu for me to even test your examples. I'm a bit stunned that no-one else seems to use it anymore. There were times, when it was hyped very much.

Comment: Thanks Halirutan, I hope to get things working eventually. I am a little surprised too, it seems to have so much potential. I'd like to collect a bunch of working examples for others to use. WCC

Comment: The main reason why I don't use it anymore is that it is a pain to keep things working throughout all operating systems but more important is, that my colleagues don't have the hardware I have and it is very likely I have to rewrite code if I want to share the CUDA stuff.