# Looking for a working mathematica CUDA port of NVIDIA's nbody.cu

Tags: reference-request, cudalink, gpu

I am trying to extend an example that is provided as one of NVIDIA's prototypical examples: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-n-body-simulation

I'm trying, but haven't been successful in getting that example to work with Mathematica. If anyone out there has been successful doing this, I would be very grateful to receive a version.

It is so much easier to extend a working example, than to get an example to extend working....

This is related to a previous post:
[Beginner CUDA: two dimensional blocks and two dimensional threads?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/beginner-cuda-two-dimensional-blocks-and-two-dimensional-threads)