# A simple experiment to understand CUDAFunctionLoad

Tags: cudalink, gpu

In an attempt to answer my own question ([Beginner CUDA: two dimensional blocks and two dimensional threads?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/beginner-cuda-two-dimensional-blocks-and-two-dimensional-threads)).

Please excuse the long post, it contains for examples I constructed as an experiment to understand what is going on.  *(postscript: on the advice of @rojo, I am clarifying my question; so the post is getting longer. New edits in italics).*

I've constructed the simplest CUDA code example I can think of, but I don't understand the results.  **I would be grateful if someone with more CUDAFunctionLoad experience than I could give me an explanation.**

```
src = "__global__ void query(mint * idx, mint * tinx, mint * tiny, \
mint * binx, mint *biny, mint * bdimx, mint *bdimy, mint * gdimx, \
mint * gdimy, mint length)
   {
      int index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
      if (index < length)
          {
          idx[index] = index;
          tinx[index] = threadIdx.x  ;
          tiny[index] = threadIdx.y;
          binx[index] = blockIdx.x  ;
          biny[index] = blockIdx.y;
          bdimx[index] = blockDim.x; 
          bdimy[index] = blockDim.y;
          gdimx[index] = gridDim.x; 
          gdimy[index] = gridDim.y;
          }
  }";
```

Use CUDAFunctionLoad with a {16,8} blockdim argument:

```
simpleCUDA = 
 CUDAFunctionLoad[src, 
  "query", {{_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, 
    "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, 
    "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, 
    "Output"}, _Integer}, {16, 8}, "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print]


headings = {"index", "thread index x", "thread index y", 
   "block index x", "block index y", "block dimension x", 
   "block dimension y", "grid dimension x", "grid dimension y"};
avec = Range[20];
```

Call this function without the optional threads last argument:

*(Why are the grid dimensions {2,1}? The thread index y changes at index 16 as expected, but why are the indices 7 and then 3--are these chosen at random?)*

```
MatrixForm@
 Transpose@
  Prepend[Transpose@
    simpleCUDA[avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, 
     20], headings]
```

With result:
[image]

Call the function with the optional threads final argument (e.g. 6):

*(Why should the grid dimensions change at index 16? How does one understand the effect of the final argument 6?)*

```
MatrixForm@
 Transpose@
  Prepend[Transpose@
    simpleCUDA[avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, 
     20, 6], headings]
```

Result:
[image]

Use CUDAFunctionLoad with a single blockdim argument (e.g., 8)

```
simpleCUDAalt = 
  CUDAFunctionLoad[{getSource["simple.cu"]}, 
   "query", {{_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, 
     "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer,
      "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, {_Integer, 
     "Output"}, {_Integer, "Output"}, _Integer}, 8, 
   "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print];
```

Call this function without the optional thread argument:

```
MatrixForm@
 Transpose@
  Prepend[Transpose@
    simpleCUDAalt[avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, 
     avec, 20], headings]
```

Result:

*(Why are the grid dimensions now {1,1} when previously they were {2,1}? Why do the grid dimensions change at index 16? Is it that I am accessing memory that hasn't been cleared?)*

It looks like I am only allowed to put 2 images in a single post--the editor is not allowing me to put in a 3rd.  So, I will cut and paste Output

```
{
 {"index", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 
  18, 19, 20},
 {"thread index x", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
  15, 17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"thread index y", 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
  17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"block index x", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17,
   18, 19, 20},
 {"block index y", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17,
   18, 19, 20},
 {"block dimension x", 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
   16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"block dimension y", 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
   17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"grid dimension x", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
  17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"grid dimension y", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
  17, 18, 19, 20}
}
```

Lastly, call the function with the additional threads argument (e.g., 12).

```
MatrixForm@
 Transpose@
  Prepend[Transpose@
    simpleCUDAalt[avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, avec, 
     avec, 20, 12], headings]
```

Result:

*(Why do the block dimensions change as well here?)*

```
{
 {"index", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 
  18, 19, 20},
 {"thread index x", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
  17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"thread index y", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"block index x", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 17,
   18, 19, 20},
 {"block index y", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17,
   18, 19, 20},
 {"block dimension x", 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
   17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"block dimension y", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"grid dimension x", 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
  17, 18, 19, 20},
 {"grid dimension y", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
  17, 18, 19, 20}
}
```

Comment: You should post a more concrete question. What result where you expecting and why and where does it differ from what you get?

Comment: Last comment was cut off. I will edit the post, but I fear that the post will become too long. . The problem is that I don't understand the documentation, and thus the experiments to figure it out. Thus, I didn't know what to expect, but I cannot understand how my results correspond to the documentation. I'm hopeful that someone with CUDA experience will see it and offer a pedagogical explanation.

Comment: The link in the post goes to the original question.

Comment: Postscript. Unless I missed it before, there is now an example of three dimensional blocks the documentation for CUDAFunctionLoad.  I just updated to M10.0.2 from M10.0.1.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I used to more or less get CudaFunctionLoad, but I haven't used it in a while, and for a few more days I am far from my dear home PC with a CUDA GPU to try. Hope someone answers soon :)

Comment: Thanks Rojo (I'm fairly new to SE so I don't know how much chitchat is kosher).  I've made a bit of progress, but am still working on getting a nontrivial example working. Unfortunately, I'm going to have to take a break from my attempts for a few weeks. Thanks for the kind kind  words. Craig

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured this block and grid dimension stuff out. First, here's a simpler kernel for checking:

```
dementiaSource = "
  __global__ void dementia( mint *out )
  {
    out[0] = blockDim.x;
    out[1] = blockDim.y;
    out[2] = blockDim.z;
    out[3] = gridDim.x;
    out[4] = gridDim.y;
    out[5] = gridDim.z;
  }";
```

This, of course, is highly redundant, with every thread poking the same values into the output array, but it does the job.

Make an instance with diagnostic block dimensions:

```
dementia = CUDAFunctionLoad[dementiaSource, "dementia", 
  {{_Integer, _, "Output"}}, {3, 5, 7}]
```

Now, invoke it with diagnostic dimensions:

```
dementia[ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {11, 13}]
(* {{3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 1}} *)
```

Note the the grid X dimension, 4, is `Ceiling[11/3]` and the grid Y dimension, 3, is `Ceiling[13/5]`. More experiments confirm that this appears to be a general rule.

My interpretation of this is that while CUDA's model of threading is six dimensional, CUDALink's model is basically two dimensional. CUDALink expects you to tile a two dimensional space with two dimensional blocks. The dimensions you provide to the `CUDAFunction` are not the grid dimensions, but the dimensions of the space you are tiling in elements (pixels). CUDALink rounds up the X and Y grid dimensions as needed to completely cover the space. The Z block dimension given `CUDAFunctionLoad` is used, but there is no corresponding Z dimension in the `CUDAFunction` parameters. To recover a five dimensional model, the dimensions provided to the  `CUDAFunction` should be `{gx*bx,gy*by}` where `gx` is the X grid dimension, and `bx` is the X block dimension, etc. There appears to be no way to specify a grid Z dimension.

Comment: Thanks for remembering my post John. I need to update my nvidia drivers and then study this. Thanks, Craig